# Difference of directories using 'diff' command in shell script without the details

Tags: shell, diff

The `diff` command gives a list of details along with the difference of files/folders like this

```
dirs=`diff -aq new_dir/ old_dir`
```

gives:

```
Only in new_dir/: five Common subdirectories: new_dir/four and old_dir/four Common subdirectories: new_dir/one and old_dir/one
```

But I want only the folder/file name without the details that is: five,four and etc. That is without the details

I tried something like this:

```
dirs=diff -aq new_dir/ old_dir | grep 'Only in new_dir/: *'
```

I don't think this is the right way to get ONLY the difference of folders. Is there any better way to solve this?

My desired output:

```
five
seven 
six
```

and Not

```
Only in new_dir/: five 
Only in new_dir/: seven 
Only in new_dir/: six
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to see items which are `Common` in both? Or I am misunderstanding your question? Can you show your desired output? Also, do quote your `dirs` variable so that newlines are pressured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
dir=$(diff -aq new_dir/ old_dir | awk -F": " '/Only in new_dir/{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to know what (sub-)directories exist in `dirA` that don't exist in `dirB`, you can do this:

```
comm -23 <(cd dirA; find . -type d -print | sort) <(cd dirB; find . -type d -print | sort)
```

That doesn't consider the actual *contents* of directories though. You could adapt the above to find the reverse - sub directories in `dirB` but not `dirA` - by replacing `-23` with `-13`; or get the common subdirectories with `comm -12`.

It would get more difficult if you cared about the *files* in each directory or the *contents* of those files, but it seems like that may not be the case here...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But @JS웃's is more relevant to me